# Определение принадлежности точек одной плоскости по расстояниям между ними

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Имеем 4 точки в пространстве. Известны расстояния между каждой парой из этих точек.

Как определить принадлежат ли эти 4 точки одной плоскости?

Есть ли аналогичный алгоритм для любого количества точек?

Answer (score 14):

Все четыре точки (A, B, C и D) будут лежать в одной плоскости тогда и только тогда, когда объем тетраэдра с вершинами в этих четырех точках будет равен `0`. Так что все, что нам нужно - это уметь вычислять объем тетраэдра по длинам его сторон.

Это можно сделать через [определитель Кэли-Менгера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.8A.D1.91.D0.BC_.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.8D.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B0)

```
           | 0     1        1        1        1    |
           | 1     0     d2(A,B)  d2(A,C)  d2(A,D) |
V = sqrt ( | 1  d2(A,B)     0     d2(B,C)  d2(B,D) | / 288 )
           | 1  d2(A,C)  d2(B,C)     0     d2(C,D) |
           | 1  d2(A,D)  d2(B,D)  d2(C,D)     0    |
```

где d2(A, B) - *квадраты* соответствующих длин сторон.

Это фактически трехмерная версия известной формулы Герона для площади треугольника.

---

В качестве более "осязаемого"/"конструктивного" решения задачи можно предложить рассмотреть треугольники ABC и ABD. Если эти треугольники лежат в одной плоскости, то расстояние CD может равняться только одному из двух значений: одно значение расстояния для ситуации, когда С и D лежат по одну сторону от AB, другое - когда С и D лежат по разные стороны от AB.

Не составит труда построить треугольники ABC и ABD на плоскости (например, положив точку A в начало координат, а точку B на ось абсцисс), вычислить конкретные координаты точек C и D и узнать искомые расстояния для планарного случая. После этого остается лишь сравнить найденные расстояния с данным в условии расстоянием CD.

---

Вопрос о большем количестве точек не совсем понятен. Речь идет об N точек в N-1-мерном пространстве? Или речь идет об N точек в *трехмерном* пространстве? В последнем случае задача сводится просто к применению одного из вышеприведенных решений к четверкам точек среди данных N. Лучше всего, наверное, действовать иерархически: проверить на планарность независимые четверки, а затем уже проверять планарность между четверками.